# Editing this.state content before setState in React

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering if this sort of code would cause side effects.

Let's say I have some state object in a component that contains an array which itself contains objects with various properties:

```
getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            willContainObjects: [];
}
```

Now, I have a function which will edit that object and then create a new state object:

```
editObjectInArray: function (index) {
    var obj= this.state.willContainObjects[index];
    obj.someProp = 3; // mutating this.state!!!
    this.setState({
    willContainObjects: this.state.willContainObjects.slice(0, index)
                       .concat(details)
                       .concat(this.state.willContainObjects.slice(index+1))
    }); // end setState
},
```

`obj.someProp = 3` mutated the state of `this.state` directly, but right before calling `this.setState` and causing re-render. Will this direct mutation of state before calling `setState` have any unintended side-effects? I know React recommends not to do this but I think this is an exception. I could use `Object.assign` to create a new object instead of mutating, but I don't see a point of doing this in this case.

Comment: @zerkms that isn't really true.  React does not assume the objects in `state` are immutable.  You have to opt into that assumption by implementing `componentShouldUpdate`.

Comment: OP isn't mutating `this.state`.  OP is mutating a child object of `this.state`.  React honors such mutations by default as long as you eventually call `this.setState()` or `this.forceUpdate()`.

Comment: @zerkms according to the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)? Pay particular attention to the **Notes** section, especially about mutable objects in your state.

Comment: @Brandon now this is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only "side-effect" will be that any components that use the PureRenderMixin or implement a `shouldComponentUpdate` method that uses a shallow equality test may not understand that the object has really changed.

Other than that, though not recommended, it should work OK.