# ESLint: Use callback in setState when referencing the previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

For this piece of code I am getting eslint(AirBnb config) error:
Use callback in setState when referencing the previous state

Does this error influence performance somehow and how can it be solved?

```
  handleSelect(event) {
    const entry = event.nativeEvent;

    if (entry == null) {
      this.setState({ ...this.state, selectedEntry: entry });
    } else
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        selectedEntry: JSON.stringify(entry),
        markerIsEnabled: true
      });

    console.log(event.nativeEvent);
  }
```

Comment: What is the expected result of your question? You only want to know why you get this error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this.state inside setState ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817798/this-state-inside-setstate-reactjs)

Comment: You can remove `...this.state` from `setState`. It will only update parameters in the state you have changed.

Answer (score 8):

As you can see in [documentation](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-access-state-in-setstate.md)

> This rule should prevent usage of this.state inside setState calls. Such usage of this.state might result in errors when two state calls are called in batch and thus referencing old state and not the current state. An example can be an increment function:
>
> ```
> function increment() {
>   this.setState({value: this.state.value + 1});
> }
> ```
>
> If these two setState operations is grouped together in a batch it will look be something like the following, given that value is 1:
>
> ```
> setState({value: 1 + 1})
> setState({value: 1 + 1})
> ```
>
> This can be avoided with using callbacks which takes the previous state as first argument:
>
> ```
> function increment() {
>   this.setState(prevState => ({value: prevState.value + 1}));
> }
> ```

So this is why you have that rule, to avoid erros like this example.

In your case, what you should do is

```
handleSelect({ nativeEvent }) {    
    if (nativeEvent == null) {
        this.setState(previousState => ({
            ...previousState, 
            selectedEntry: nativeEvent
        }));
    } else {
      this.setState(previousState => ({
        ...previousState,
        selectedEntry: JSON.stringify(entry),
        markerIsEnabled: true
      }));
    }
}
```

But for your case, this an error won't happen because you don't have two consecutives `setState` and also, `...this.state` or `...prevState` won't make any diference because you aren't using the previous state to set a new state.

So for the code you provided in your question, just remove `...this.state` and it will work fine, with no errors.

Answer (score 6):

You can remove `...this.state` from `setState` because it will only update parameters in the state you have changed.

You can see in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) that `setState(stateChange)` performs a performs a shallow merge of stateChange into the state.

```
Object.assign(
  previousState,
  stateChange,
  ...
)
```

This means you don't need to be passing your previous state in, unless new properties depend on it, as `setState` will do this merge for you.

```
handleSelect(event) {
    const entry = event.nativeEvent;

    if (entry == null) {
      this.setState({ selectedEntry: entry });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        selectedEntry: JSON.stringify(entry),
        markerIsEnabled: true
      });
    }

    console.log(event.nativeEvent);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It's because `setState` is async.

```
handleSelect({ nativeEvent }) {

    if (nativeEvent == null) {
        this.setState((previousState) => ({
            ...previousState, selectedEntry: nativeEvent
        }));
    } else
      this.setState((previousState) => ({
        ...previousState,
        selectedEntry: JSON.stringify(entry),
        markerIsEnabled: true
      }));
  }
```

Comment: why is `...previousState` is needed here at all?

Comment: Right, could be omitted at all - which also removes the need for a callback. 