# Delete mapped element by click React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

In my state I have an array, which I mapped in `render` function:

**State**

```
this.state = {
        newItem: {
            name: "",
            amount: 0
        },
        products: [
            {
                name: "Item",
                amount: 5
            },
            {
                name: "Item",
                amount: 5
            },
            {
                name: "Item",
                amount: 5
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to delete element from the array products by clicking in button of that element. But what I attempted to do, everything fails. I searched a lot and find logically the most common solution but it didn't work too. Here is the delete function:

**Delete function**

```
delete(e) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ products: prevState.products.filter((product) => {
      return product !== e.target.value
  })}))
  console.table(this.state.products)
}
```

**Mapped JSX code**

```
            {
                this.state.products.map((item, index) => {
                    return(
                        <div key={index}>
                            <input readOnly value={this.state.products[index].name} type="text" />
                            <button disabled>-</button>
                            <input readOnly value={this.state.products[index].amount} type="number" />
                            <button disabled>+</button>
                            <button onClick={(e) => this.delete(e)}>Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57969736/1641941) can help you out.

Comment: @HMR thanks this answer was interesting too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass index of that element into `delete` which will be removed like below.

```
<button onClick={() => delete(index)}>Delete</button>
```

Then you can remove that element easily.

```
delete = index => {
  this.setState(prevState => 
    ({
        products: prevState.products.filter((product, i) => i !== index)
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: `splice` actually modifies the array, I would prefer using `filter` method

Comment: @Antonio delete one parenthesis like this : ` products: prevState.products.filter((product, i) => i !== index)` like works only like this

Answer (score 1):

A simplified example of how to make item specific buttons on a mapped list:

```
delete = (id) => {
  this.setState(products: this.state.products.filter((item, index) => index !== idx));
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm of delete function is right, but in this case, I need exactly the code what I wrote in the edit, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `setState` is **asynchronous**, so using `console.log(this.state.products)` immediately after calling `setState` will not print the updated products. You can pass a callback in the second parameter of `setState`, it will be executed once setState is completed.

The other problem comes from the `delete` function. You are using `e.target.value` which is an empty string because the button has no value.

You can fix this with the following code :

```
delete(product) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    products: prevState.products.filter(p => p !== product)
  }), 
  () => console.log(this.state.products));
}
```

In the JSX code, I pass the product in the first argument of the `delete` function :

```
{
  this.state.products.map((product, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <input readOnly value={product.name} type="text"/>
      <button disabled>-</button>
      <input readOnly value={product.amount} type="number"/>
      <button disabled>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => this.delete(product)}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. It just doing nothing when I click

Comment: But whatever, I find the right answer and you gave me good advice, it at least deserves an upvote. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution and working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-tdd-js8yz

```js
state = {
    newItem: {
        name: "",
        amount: 0
    },
    products: [
        {
            name: "Item1",
            amount: 5
        },
        {
            name: "Item2",
            amount: 5
        },
        {
            name: "Item3",
            amount: 5
        }
    ]
}

  delete(e: any) {
    
    var products = this.state.products.filter((product) => {
      return product.name !== e.name
    });

    console.log(products)

    this.setState({products: products})
    console.table(this.state.products)
  }

  render() {
    const { products } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
      {products.map((x, index) => {
        return <div key={index}>
        <input readOnly value={this.state.products[index].name} type="text" />
        <button disabled>-</button>
        <input readOnly value={this.state.products[index].amount} type="number" />
        <button disabled>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.delete.bind(this, x)}>Delete</button>
    </div>
      })}
      </>
    )
  }
```

Comment: It is to complex, but anyway it works, it deserves at least an upvote. Thank You!